# Dividends and Number of shares owned

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, dividends

For stocks in companies that pay dividends, is this just for holding any share, or is the dividend paid per share?  For example, a dividend of $10: is that $10 for holding 200 shares of stock or $10 per share of stock?

Comment: OP, please ensure that I did not change the meaning of your question.

Comment: Variations of this question has been asked many, many times.  [For example](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/125369/dividend-calculation).

Comment: @BobBaerker that question is not a duplicate because it already knows that dividends are per share.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take your question "is that **$10 for holding 200 shares of stock** " to its logical conclusion.

In that scenario, someone who owned 2 **million** shares of stock in the company would get the same dividend as someone who owns a single share of stock.  In that light, you see that it can't be true.

Thus, the correct answer is "$10 **per share** of stock".